ASP.NET: Serving a WebAssembly application via an ASP.NET server
I have 2 projects. The first one is an ASP.NET webAssembly client web application. When I build the projet and then publish it, I get a wwwroot directory that contains all the file of the web application. This web application connect to a REST API that runs on another ASP.NET server project. I would like that my REST server also serve the client web pages. I have modify my Main with the following code:
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions { FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(serverRoot), });
When I try to open the client in Firefox, the browser try to load the file icudt_EFIGS.dat and get an error 404 (the file exists in the wwwroot directory). I have tried to serve the web application with another Static File Server, and the file icudt_EFIGS.dat is never requested by the browser... The same is true when I am debuging the application via Visual Studio and IIS Express is used.
I have tried to add a web.config file to allow the .dat files to be serve by the file Server, it has not work.
Is there something I am missing here?
Thank you
